# How to hide sidemenu after logout in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I created login and logout functionality I given logout in  side menu. Logout functionality working properly but the problem after logout side menu is seeing. How to hide side menu after logout and go
home page.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`menuClose` directive](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/menu/MenuClose/):

> The `menuClose` directive can be placed on any button to close an open
>   menu.

A simple menuClose button can be added using the following markup:

```
<button ion-button menuClose>Close Menu</button>
```

or

```
<button ion-item menuClose>Close Menu</button>
```

That would make the menu to be closed when you select the logout option from the side menu.

---

If you want to have more control over the menu, you can use the [`MenuController`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/app/MenuController/) and use it to close the menu programmatically, from the component code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage {

 constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController) {

 }

 openMenu() {
   this.menuCtrl.open();
 }

 closeMenu() {
   this.menuCtrl.close();
 }

 toggleMenu() {
   this.menuCtrl.toggle();
 }

}
```

Comment: @sabaferreras in ionic 1 when we logout and go home page it does not show sidemenu automatically hide how we can same in ionic 2 because according to your solution we have to use button for it

Comment: You can inject the `MenuController` and use it to hide it, like I show you in the last part of the answer, and by doing it like that you don't need a button, you can do `this.menuCtrl.close();` inside of the logout method

Comment: And the `menuClose` directive also works with `ion-item` acting as buttons, like you're using them in the screenshot provided in the question.

Comment: #sebaferreras but I am using  menu like <button ion-item (click)="logoutApp()">
      <!--Add this static button for logout-->
        Log Out
      </button> in app.html

Comment: What happens if you change it to: `<button menuClose ion-item (click)="logoutApp()">Log Out </button>`?

Comment: # sebaferreras last  solution working for me,Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to hear that :) I've added the last comment to the answer as well just in case if that could help other SO users.

Comment: you can also publish event with `this.menu.swipeEnable(false);` on logout and `this.menu.swipeEnable(true);` when login again

Answer (score 0):

```
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController)

logout(){
    this.menuCtrl.close();
    this.router.navigate(['home']);

}
```

Latest Ionic version code may be used like this.